# Having trouble with turtles

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am having an issue with turtles.

This is the code so far:

```
'''
Levi Davis
This program demonstrates my knowledge on turtles based on problem one in the
third set of homework questions
'''

import turtle
import math

def draw_arc(t, angle, num_segments, length):
    '''
    draws an arc with turtle 't' that has a number of segments equal to 'num_segments'
    and a length equal to 'length' with a turn angle of 'angle' divided by 'num_segments'
    '''

    #this is my calculations on the actual turning of the turtle
    turn_angle = angle // num_segments
    init_turn = ((num_segments - 1) * turn_angle) // 2

    #the initial turn of the turtle and the loop to make the arc
    t.right(init_turn)
    for count in range(num_segments):
        t.forward(length/num_segments)
        t.left(turn_angle)

    #undoing the final turn and the initial turn
    t.right(turn_angle + init_turn)

def draw_squiggle(t, angle, num_segments, length, num_squiggles):
    '''
    This function utilizes draw_arc() to create a squiggly line
    '''
    for x in range(num_squiggles):
        draw_arc(t, angle, num_segments, length)
        draw_arc(t, -(angle), num_segments, length)

def draw_petal(t, angle, num_segments, length):
    '''
    draws a filled in petal shape using 2 arcs and a 180 degree turn
    '''
    t.begin_fill()
    draw_arc(t, angle, num_segments, length)
    t.left(180)
    draw_arc(t, angle, num_segments, length)
    t.left(180)
    t.end_fill()

def draw_leaf(t, angle, num_segments, length):
    draw_petal(t, angle, num_segments, length)
    t.fillcolor(t.pencolor())
    draw_petal(t, angle, num_segments, (length / 2))

wn = turtle.Screen()


bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.pencolor("tomato2")
bob.pensize(5)
bob.fillcolor("black")


#Because clare told me to I made her into a turtle
clare = turtle.Turtle()
clarepen = "green"
clarefill = "purple"
clare.pencolor(clarepen)
clare.pensize(3)
clare.fillcolor(clarefill)

#testing of functions

   #draw_arc(bob, 100, 10, 10)
   #draw_arc(bob, -100, 10, 10)
   #draw_squiggle(bob, -100, 10, 10, 2)
   #draw_petal(clare, 100, 10, 40)
   #draw_leaf(clare, 100, 10, 40)

#that one shape that is kind of trippy to look at... I think?...
size = 80
def draw_weird_shape(t1, t2):
    startx = -size / 2
    starty = -size / 2 * math.tan(math.radians(144 /2))
    t1.up()
    t1.goto(startx, starty)
    t1.down()
    t2.up()
    t2.goto(startx, starty)
    t2.down()

    t1_fill = "purple"
    t1_pen = "green"

    for count in range(10):
        t1.forward(size/2)
        t1.right(90)
        draw_squiggle(t1, 50, 10, 20, 2)
        draw_leaf(t1, 50, 10, 50)
        t1.pencolor(t1_pen)
        t1.fillcolor(t1_fill)
        t1.right(180)
        draw_squiggle(t1, 50, 10, 20, 2)
        t1.right(90)
        t1.forward(size/2)
        t1.left(36)        
        t2.up()
        t2.forward(size)
        t2.left(18)
        t2.right(90)
        t2.down()
        draw_petal(t2, 50, 5, 25)
        t2.up()
        t2.left(108)

draw_weird_shape(clare, bob)

'''
clare.forward(20)
clare.left(18)
clare.right(90)
clare.forward(20)
clare.left(180)
clare.forward(20)
clare.right(90)
clare.forward(20)
'''

wn.exitonclick()
```

The problem appears to be around line 100.

When the squiggle starts to go back it does not go back in the 180 degree turn like it should.

Answer (score 0):

> When the squiggle starts to go back it does not go back in the 180
>   degree turn like it should.

Your problem is this code:

```
#this is my calculations on the actual turning of the turtle
turn_angle = angle // num_segments
init_turn = ((num_segments - 1) * turn_angle) // 2
```

By using integer division, `//`, you introduce just enough error that the arc code underlying the squiggle doesn't retrace the same path.  Instead use floating point division, `/`, to keep it slightly more accurate:

```
# this is my calculations on the actual turning of the turtle
turn_angle = angle / num_segments
init_turn = ((num_segments - 1) * turn_angle) / 2
```

[image]
[image]